# Expanding Window combined with Percentile operation on PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, rolling-computation, quantile

I have a PySpark DataFrame with a "SPEED" column per vehicle trip and I want to calculate the 0.95 expanding(1) quantile in a new column.

That is, in Python, starting with:

```
   TRIP_ID  SPEED
0        1     90
1        1     75
2        1     60
3        2     65
4        2     80
5        2     95
6        3    100
7        3    110
8        3    115
```

and applying

```
df.groupby("TRIP_ID")["SPEED"].expanding().quantile(0.95)
```

gives (after some manipulation to the indexes and columns of the new df):

```
   TRIP_ID  SPEED  95_PERC
0        1     90    90.00
1        1     75    89.25
2        1     60    88.50
3        2     65    65.00
4        2     80    79.25
5        2     95    93.50
6        3    100   100.00
7        3    110   109.50
8        3    115   114.50
```

The last column represents the .95 quantile of column "SPEED", calculated in an expanding window fashion: a new value is calculated as a new row is added to the window.

Is there a way to do this in PySpark without having to revert to pandas DF?

Comment: please provide an example of the dataframe that you refer to...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the comment, updated with an example

Comment: glad you resolved this....  in the answer where did `F` come from ?  as there was no such variable in the original question ?

Comment: Sorry, added the relevant imports. Feedback is much appreciated as this is my first post here. Cheers!

Comment: ah, that makes more sense. given that this is the answer, you might want to also post it as the answer to your own question instead of in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved this quite easily by:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn(
    "95_PERC",
    F.expr("percentile(SPEED, array(0.95))").over(Window.partitionBy("TRIP_ID").orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
)
```

Comment: Hey, maybe a bit late but I would have liked some more explanations on why this is equivalent to the pandas expanding function.

Comment: From pySpark docs:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween.html

You can try different parameters in rowsBetween() and test it, I have done so and it produces same results as pandas.

Comment: Of course googling it was the first thing I did and of course I end up in the docs. But for it to be a great answer for your fellow programmers, it would include some personal explanation of thought process.